# install opencv3 on mac for python 3.6

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macos-sierra

I want to install opencv3 for python 3.6 on macOS Sierra. I have tried to use it through homebrew using this link 
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/ but I am getting this error

```
Error: opencv3: Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 wrappers
```

How to resolve this??

Comment: the installation of opencv changed recently, you can check my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786869/installing-opencv3-with-homebrew-no-head-is-defined-for-opencv/52220239#52220239 for developments of this problem

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --without-python`

Comment: Please provide more explanation for this answer and why it is better than the already accepted answer.

Comment: Note that, as the error message says, this means that opencv will *not* be available for Python 2.7. That is what `--without-python` means.

Comment: @PamungkasJayuda I tried it this way, and when I try import cv2 or import cv3 it gives module not found error

Comment: @user1692342: are you use VIRTUALENV ? If yes make sure inherit global site-packages

Comment: the installation of opencv changed recently, you can check my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786869/installing-opencv3-with-homebrew-no-head-is-defined-for-opencv/52220239#52220239 for developments of this problem

Answer (score 6):

this error is caused by [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/5488/commits/67c4382a025ea834dc189785c0c0fcbfe8ee4fcc) commit.

With `brew edit opencv3` you have to comment the four lines:

```
if build.with?("python3") && build.with?("python")
  # Opencv3 Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 versions
  odie "opencv3: Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 wrappers"
end
```

save and rerun the installation:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3
```

after that everything works for me

Comment: This only installs Python 3.x bindings for OpenCV.

Comment: When I ``brew search opencv3``, I get ``If you meant "opencv3" specifically:
It was migrated from homebrew/science to homebrew/core.``

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and I have resolved the issue in the following way:

$ brew edit opencv3

Find the following code block and comment all the 4 lines:

```
if build.with?("python3") && build.with?("python")
  # Opencv3 Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 versions
  odie "opencv3: Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 wrappers"
end
```

Finally install using the brew install command:

$ brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3

Reference: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/15/resolving-macos-opencv-homebrew-install-errors/

Comment: This only installs Python 3.x bindings for OpenCV.

Comment: For installing on Python 2.x , remove the --with-python3