# How do you install OpenCV3 on a mac, with both python2.7 and python3.6 bindings?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv3.0, python-3.6

I have opencv3 installed on my mac, using Homebrew for the install, with python2.7 bindings. I now want to use some code that only works with python3, that also uses opencv3, but I don't want to break the python2.7 bindings as I have other code that relies on them. How do you install opencv3 on a mac with both python2.7 and python3.x bindings, or how do you add python3.x bindings to an existing install of opencv3 without breaking the python2.7 bindings?

Comment: What causes them to break?

Comment: What I mean is that I can only find ways to install opencv3 with either python2.7 or python3.x bindings. I want both bindings, therefore my question is how? I haven't done anything that has broken anything yet, I'm just describing what I want to achieve. There is a previous post which demonstrates that Homebrew complains if both are asked for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666806/install-opencv3-on-mac-for-python-3-6

Answer (score 0):

- I think **opencv3.x** is compatible with **python3.x** and is not compatible with **python2.x**
- If you want **opencv** to work with **python2.x** then then I would suggest you to download **opencv2.x**
- If you are using anaconda and want to install opencv2.x version then run the following command : `conda install -c menpo opencv3`
- You can refer to this link if you want to install **opencv2.x** with Homebrew : https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/