# Installing OpenCV3 with Homebrew: No head is defined for opencv

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew, opencv3.0

I am having trouble installing OpenCV3 with the error I have...

> No head is defined for opencv

I have not found any solution to on the internet.
I used these websites as references:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-macos/

---

The exact steps I followed were:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
echo "# Homebrew" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

brew install python python3
brew link python
brew link python3
```

Then I tried to see what versions I had so I ran:

```
which python2
which python3
```

Only a file path for python3 existed so I decided to explicitly install python2:

```
brew install python2
```

Then it said it was already linked when I tried to link it (not sure if this is relevant to the issue, but it may be):

```
brew link python2
```

It returned:

> Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3 To
>   relink: brew unlink python@2 && brew link python@2

Then I checked it was all good with `which` again and python2 and python3 were now there.

```
python2 --version   ===> Python 2.7.14
python3 --version   ===> Python 3.6.4
```

The since the pythons (I think) are all good, I tried installing OpenCV3w with:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD
```

but the error was

> Error: No head is defined for opencv

Do I ***NEED*** the head? What's wrong with it anyway?

---

**P.S.** Not sure if this is relevant, but

```
brew info opencv3
```

gives

> opencv: stable 3.4.1 (bottled) Open source computer vision library
>   https://opencv.org/ Not installed From:
>   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv.rb
>   ==> Dependencies Build: cmake ✘, pkg-config ✘ Required: eigen ✘, ffmpeg ✘, jpeg ✘, libpng ✘, libtiff ✘, openexr ✘, python ✔, python@2
>   ✔, numpy ✘, tbb ✘

---

Thank you so much for any support, MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Compiling OpenCV can be hard, and even harderon a MacOS. Homebrew alleviates this often, but the current recipe for opencv is a good start.

However, I had problems with it, the main being that it would compile against `python2` and that I have all my toolchain in `python3`. So I created a new cask to install a [dependence on `tbb`](https://github.com/laurentperrinet/config-scripts/blob/master/tbb_py3.rb) and then one for [opencv](https://github.com/laurentperrinet/config-scripts/blob/master/opencv_py3.rb). You will not that to achieve compilation to the end, I had to remove some dependencies, and in particular that to `protobuf`.

For convenience, you can clone / download the repository and launch this script
 [script](https://github.com/laurentperrinet/config-scripts/blob/master/osx_install_opencv.sh) which cleans up things and then runs the install. Any comments are welcome!